# Ruby: working with arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am working on a script that collects all comments from my DB and inserts them into a hash. I then do a collect on the comments hash and split the comments into two separate comment hashes (vid_comments & wall_comments)

```
w_hash["comments"] << contender.profile.comments.where("created_at > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)")
    w_hash["comments"].delete_if { |x| x.blank? }
    w_hash["vid_comments"], w_hash["wall_comments"] = [], []

    w_hash["comments"].each do |c|
      if !c.media_id.nil?
        w_hash["vid_comments"] << c
      elsif c.parent_id == 0
        w_hash["wall_comments"] << c
      end
    end
```

Is there anyway to shorten the code? I am pretty new to Ruby (PHP import) so excuse my ignorance in things I may be doing wrong.

EDIT: Added in code bit from @Mchl (below)..

Comment: Consider moving your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks! Post moved to codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/ruby-working-with-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I see (being a recent PHP import myself) would be to change this:

```
w_hash["vid_comments"] = w_hash["comments"].collect { |c| !c.media_id.nil? }
w_hash["wall_comments"] = w_hash["comments"].collect { |w| w.parent_id == 0 }
```

Into

```
w_hash["comments"].each do |c|
  if !c.media_id.nil?
    w_hash["vid_comments"] << c
  elsif c.parent_id == 0
    w_hash["wall_comments"] << c
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!! I have recently been introduced to the `.collect` method in Ruby and have been trying to get better at DRY(ing) up my code! Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's probably a way to do it all in one simple and elegant line, but I'm not there yet ;P

Comment: Me either :P I ended up modifying your code slightly... I pasted the new above